How do I change the color of some text once the user stops interacting with the screen?
I have a timer/stopwatch in my app, and the default color of the text is white. I've managed to change the color of the text if you long-press on the screen. In other words, if the text is white and you long-press, it will turn green, and vice versa.
What I want now is to make it so that once the user stops long-tapping the screen, that the text reverts back to white. For example, say the user has white text. Once he long-presses on the screen, the text turns green, but as soon as he lifts his finger, the text should revert back to white. I've tried multiple things, such as wrapping my TextButton() in a GestureDetector so as to get access to the multiple onTap options, but I cannot seem to get my desired outcome. I'm not very experienced with Flutter, so any help and explanation as to what I am doing wrong is greatly appreciated.
Code for the timer text:
              child: GestureDetector(
                  // onTapDown: (details) => timercolor = Colors.white,
                  child: TextButton(
                    onLongPress: (){
                      setState(() {
                        timercolor = timercolor == Colors.white
                            ? Colors.green.shade600
                            : Colors.white;
                        startStopWatch();
                      });
                    },
                    style: ButtonStyle(
                      overlayColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.transparent),
                    ),
                    onPressed: startStopWatch,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 210.0, bottom: 360),
                      child: Text(
                        stopWatchText,
                        style:  TextStyle(fontSize: 50, color: timercolor),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),


Here is what I came up with. It does mostly what you want, minus 1 caveat: I cannot seem to make the timer color change to green when simply long-pressing it, whilst still getting the other desired results. Apart from that, this code runs perfectly. If the timer text is long-tapped and kept long-tapped, nothing will happen. As soon as the user lift his finger though, the timer will change to green and the timer will start. Once you stop the timer, the text changes back to white. I hope this at least helps you somewhat, and that you can build on this block of code going forward to achieve the perfect outcome that you seek. Let me know if this helped.
             child: InkWell(
                    splashColor: Colors.transparent,
                    highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
                    onTap: () {
                     startStopWatch();
                      timercolor = Colors.white;
                    },
                    child: GestureDetector(
                      onLongPressStart: (_) {
                        timercolor = Colors.white;
                      },
                      onLongPressEnd: (_) {
                        timercolor = Colors.green.shade600;
                        startStopWatch();
                      },
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 210.0,                                              bottom: 360, left: 106),
                        child: Text(
                          stopWatchText,
                          style:  TextStyle(fontSize: 50, color:                              timercolor),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),


Thank you for the reply. I have tried this code, and whilst not exactly what I wanted, it is pretty close. This is the best answer so far, thank you!

here is compiled solutions buddy have fun with creativity !
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class xyzClass extends StatefulWidget {
  const xyzClass({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<xyzClass> createState() => _xyzClassState();
}

class _xyzClassState extends State<xyzClass> {
  Color textColor = Colors.white;
  String stopWatchText = "countdown";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.blue.withOpacity(.35),
      body: GestureDetector(
        onLongPressEnd: ((details) {
          updateTextColor(Colors.white);
        }),
        onLongPressStart: (details) {
          updateTextColor(Colors.green);
        },
        child: TextButton(
          style: ButtonStyle(
            overlayColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.transparent),
          ),
          onPressed: startStopWatch,
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 210.0, bottom: 360),
            child: Text(
              stopWatchText,
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 50, color: textColor),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  updateTextColor(Color value) {
    setState(() {
      textColor = value;
    });
  }

  startStopWatch() {}
}


child: InkWell(
  onLongPress: () {
    setState(() {
      timercolor = Colors.green.shade600;
    });
  },
  onTap: () {},  // This is left empty intentionally.
  onHighlightChanged: (isHighlighted) {
    if (!isHighlighted) {
      setState(() {
        timercolor = Colors.white;
        startStopWatch();
      });
    }
  },
  child: Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 210.0, bottom: 360),
    child: Text(
      stopWatchText,
      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 50, color: timercolor),
    ),
  ),
),


Thanks for the explanation, I didn't know that was what onHighlightedChanged was for. However, this code doesn't work fully, as it gives the error "The named parameter 'onHighlightChanged' isn't defined."

You're right, onHighlightChanged is not a parameter for TextButton. Instead, we can use the InkWell widget to achieve this behavior. The InkWell widget has properties such as onTap and onLongPress, and it can be wrapped around your TextButton to achieve the desired effect.
Here's how you can modify your code:

Thanks, this basically works. However, is there a way to add in a delay? I want the user to be able to long press on the screen for as much as they want to, and when they let go the timer starts. Here the timer starts as soon as the text changes to green.

Also, the text stays green after the user stops long-pressing. I needed the text to go back to white, as explained in the original post.

in this new code:
onLongPress is used to change the text color to green.
onHighlightChanged is used to detect when the user releases the long press. When isHighlighted is false (i.e., the user has lifted their finger), it changes the text color back to white and starts the stopwatch.
This approach ensures that the text color changes back to white when the user stops the long press, and the timer starts only after the user releases the long press.

Same problem, the stopwatch starts right after the text changes to green, and it does not witch back to white after I stop interacting with the screen.

I have simplified the solution by adding Mouse Region on top of Gesture Detector. I have also used container instead of a button.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class GestureDetectorLongPress extends StatefulWidget {
  const GestureDetectorLongPress({super.key});

  @override
  State<GestureDetectorLongPress> createState() => _GestureDetectorLongPressState();
}

class _GestureDetectorLongPressState extends State<GestureDetectorLongPress> {
  Color timerColor = Colors.green;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.surface,
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Overflow Practice'), centerTitle: true),
      body: SizedBox(
          width: 450,
          child: MouseRegion(
            cursor: SystemMouseCursors.click,
            child: GestureDetector(
              onLongPressStart: (_) => setState(() => timerColor = Colors.red),
              onLongPressEnd: (_) => setState(() => timerColor = Colors.green),
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0), color: timerColor),
                child: const Text('Button', textAlign: TextAlign.center),
              ),
            ),
          )),
    );
  }
}

